# postgres query explanation for aggregate with group by

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

> SELECT AVG(CAST(overview ->> 'keywords' AS INTEGER )) FROM reports
>   GROUP BY DOMAIN;

I have this in an existing project. I need to know what exactly is this query doing and how it is done?

overview is a JSON field and keywords is just an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

It sequentially scans the whole `reports` table, detoasts the `overview` column and also fetches the `domain` column, extracts the `keywords` property from `overview` and converts it to an integer, groups the results by `domain` and calculates the average of the integer values per group.

Comment: Then it should return average per each group right? Or a single average?

Comment: I have one more question. 
Need to find average of json field `keywords` from `reports` and should be **unique** by field `domain` and latest by field `ceated_at`

Comment: Yes, it will return one average per group. I don't understand your second question. You should read up about SQL (I recommend the PostgreSQL manual for an introduction to SQL), and if you have a concrete question (with an example what you mean), start a new question.